# Android Studio: How to fix "Cannot resolve symbol 'core'"

Tags: java, import, symbols

I'm getting the following errors in my Java code in Android Studio. How do I fix it?

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull'
Cannot resolve symbol 'core'
Cannot resolve symbol 'NotificationCompat'
```

Here is a code snippet associated with this error.

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class MyForegroundService extends Service {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        createNotificationChannel();
        // Create a notification for the foreground service
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
```

I have the followings in build.gradle as suggested by some work around but it doesn't help to resolve the issue.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this import might be missing from your Gradle which is used frequently:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
```

If this doesn’t work, you can take a combination of the usual steps of cleaning the project, rebuilding it, invalidating your caches and restarting Android Studio.

Otherwise, it might be useful to try to revert to older versions of said libraries as there may be breaking changes in the new versions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the issues.